# how to delete all content in database using couch db in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb

In active record rails, bellow syntax can delete all content in database

```
User.delete_all
```

questions how to delete all user in couchdb rails?

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing anything about your lib, but if you want to delete all documents, like clearing, you could do a simple `GET` against the system view: `_all_docs` (`http://localhost:5984/samples/_all_docs`), extract the `_id` and `_rev` values and then do a `bulk delete`.

Make a `POST` against `http://localhost:5984/samples/_bulk_docs`

The body should be JSON looking like this:

```
{"docs":[
    {"_id":"{0}","_rev":"{1}","_deleted":true},
    {"_id":"{0}","_rev":"{1}","_deleted":true}
]}
```

where `{0}` and `{1}` are placeholders for where you should insert your values.

**NOTE!** This will clear design docs and everything.